# The [telephony] tag, is it good or bad?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know, calling names is bad, but I'd say this time it's warranted to do so.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980306/p-bear) [has been mass-retagging questions with the](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980306/p-bear?tab=activity) [telephony](/questions/tagged/telephony) tag. Most of his rep is also assembled from these suggested edits.

I'm not sure if that's a good thing, personally I see no point in this tag, it doesn't add anything of value. As said, additionally the user has 126 rep, only 30 of this comes from questions and answers, the rest is from those suggested edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Telephony` is a legitimate topic, though whether it applied to those questions would have to be decided on a case-by-case basis.

**BUT** it did get decided on a case-by-case basis, since for suggested edits to happen, three people have to make a decision, one to create the edit, and two to approve it (though that doesn't mean they didn't mess up).

All in all, 96 rep is pretty small potatoes.

Comment: True, but I always get a little bit itchy if I see such patterns/mass-retaggings...

Comment: @Padded, I've done it before also, sometimes you see a tagging problem and if you want to clean it up, it's one question at a time.