# The [adventure] tag should be deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I noticed the newish [adventure](/questions/tagged/adventure) tag is being liberally applied today while reviewing edits. The wiki for this tag was created just today. It seems to be a meta-tag and serve no programming purpose.

Seems to be a similar case to [The [telephony] tag, is it good or bad?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109281/the-telephony-tag-is-it-good-or-bad)

Comment: That's adorable.

Comment: Reminds me of [Choose Your Own Adventure Books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choose_Your_Own_Adventure)

Comment: The tag itself has existed [since June at least](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162696/python-globally-accessable-function); it's only the tag wiki that was created today - and [Textmode](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2712809/textmode) apparently added it to [almost 30 questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventure?sort=active&pagesize=15).

Comment: Erm, Perhaps I was a little overeager... FWIW, I have been trying to select topics that deserved the tags, and making relevant side-edits.  Regardless, I'll stop until this is resolved, naturally.

Comment: Related: [`tic-tac-toe` was deemed keepable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164404/tag-merge-or-burninate-candidates-tic-tac-toe-and-tictactoe?answertab=votes#tab-top), as were `chess` and `2d-games`.

Comment: The only thing wrong I see is that "Adventure" is non-descriptive. "Adventure-game" may be better, or maybe "Text-adventure-game", or "Text-adventure". I see [quite a few questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adventure+text) has both [tag:adventure] and [tag:text] tags, which just seems wrong, neither tells you much on their own.

Comment: @Textmode I think the side edits were very useful. Perhaps I was overeager on the tag criticism?

Comment: @bluefeet: Those are the best.

Comment: @Dukeling that would make it consistent with the tags Martijn and I mentioned.

Comment: @Dukeling I think the abiguity is because at least some users (of the original uses of the tag) seemed to have been intended to refer to *Graphical* adventure games. Which obviously wouldn't be covered under [tag:Text-Adventure] (which is, incidentally, considered archaic Vs the  (ironically defunct) [tag:Interactive-Fiction]). ((but I'm pushing the bounds of a single comment now))

Comment: I don't see why it should be removed, but it should be renamed (either through manual retagging or by moderator intervention). Since it's exclusively about text-mode adventure games, it should be something like [tag:text-adventure-game].

Comment: (Regardless, I take the hint that I should be spreading my efforts more evenly)

Comment: @Textmode part of the issue is doing them all at the same time - most people don't want to see a front page full of text adventure questions.  A couple at a time every few hours is far more palatable then 5 or 6 all done within a few minutes of each other.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah, yes. I can see that is probably not overly desirable.

Comment: @Textmode and while it does look like you are doing so, I feel obliged to mention that while retagging is great for organizing questions, don't forget to clean up the question itself.  I spot checked a few of yours and they look good, but you did leave a ["Thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) in one question.  Not the end of the world but something you missed.

Comment: I wasn't sure how Judiciously I should kill the 'thanks'. '-SomeUser' were obviously redundant and I killed them where I saw them, though. (To my shame, there was a few dire posts whose internal formatting I was afraid to touch; the switch-case of doom springs to mind.)

Comment: @Textmode For "thanks", read the question I linked.  If you mean code by "internal formatting", you should rarely edit code in questions, except maybe to clean up formatting (that is intend it better to make it more readable), but refactoring questions is not advisable.  [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88629/182513) might be helpful too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is precedent for tags that describe making of specific games (or at least genre of games).

For example,

- [sudoku](/questions/tagged/sudoku) was [kept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190044/should-we-burn-sudoku)
- [tic-tac-toe](/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe) was also deemed [worthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164404/tag-merge-or-burninate-candidates-tic-tac-toe-and-tictactoe)
- [chess](/questions/tagged/chess), [2d-games](/questions/tagged/2d-games), [conways-game-of-life](/questions/tagged/conways-game-of-life), and [tiles-game](/questions/tagged/tiles-game) all continue to exist

Given this precedence, I don't think it should be deleted unless we want to revisit the previous decisions.  However as suggested by [@Textmode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195092/the-adventure-tag-should-be-deleted#comment614461_195092), maybe renaming it to [text-adventure-game](/questions/tagged/text-adventure-game) or [interactive-fiction](/questions/tagged/interactive-fiction) would be more appropriate.

Since "interactive fiction", while being more accurate is less obvious for unfamiliar users, maybe both tags should exist:

- Rename [adventure](/questions/tagged/adventure) to [text-adventure-game](/questions/tagged/text-adventure-game)
- Make it a synonym of a new [interactive-fiction-game](/questions/tagged/interactive-fiction-game) tag.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the genre's Community seems to prefer 'Interactive Fiction' as formal, and *more general* term. (Though I also ceed that *no one ever guesses that* as the name of the genre.) one of these two should (s) the other, imo.

Comment: @Textmode updated and I made this CW as I originally intended since much of this was borrowed from various comments.

Comment: +1 I agree this is a good resolution